# crontab issue while scheduling

Tags: linux, cron

I have a perl script and I scheduled it to run daily through crontab. The script is working fine if executed. But while executing through crontab, it's posting error mail to my mailbox.

Is there any thing that I should modify to successfully execute the script through crontab?

Comment: What does the error mail say?

Comment: its saying No such file/dir ...I'm using system command like system(). The error is occuring here..

Answer (score 2):

1. It could be a `$PATH` problem. Ensure that your Perl script either is on a place mentioned by `$PATH`, or has an absolute path in the crontab. This is also valid for any script or program that you run in the Perl script. The `$PATH` variable usually has to be set inside the crontab file.
2. It could be a file used in the Perl script having relative path, which could work when executed manually, but fail when run by `cron` (different working directories).
3. Does the Perl script have execute permissions (the `x` mode bit set)? This is not necessary when it's run with `perl /path/to/script.pl`, but would fail when it's run with `/path/to/script.pl`.

EDITED:

Suggestions for how to fix:

Add to `$PATH` in the crontab (for the sample script `/path/to/script.pl`):

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/path/to
```

Remember to include other needed paths as well (e.g. `/bin` and `/usr/ucb`).

Chances are there already is a `PATH` definition in the file. In that case, just append your path to it.

Alternatively, you can specify full path in the cron job line, e.g.:

```
17 *    * * *   root    /path/to/script.pl
```

To fix permissions:

```
chmod a+r+x /path/to/script.pl
```

Comment: Hi maxelsoft, I believe the first two points mentioned by you might be the reason. Can you please elaborate it.  How can I make $PATH point to my perl script path or how can I add the script path to $PATH?

Comment: It looks like PATH=$PATH:/path/to doesn't work as cron will not replace the $PATH with what the variable contains but will instead literally set the PATH variable to "$PATH:/path/to" which obviously breaks a lot of stuff. I checked in the emails cron sends out and in my case the PATH is documented in the line "X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>". So I'm now setting PATH explicitly in the crontab to PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/my/path